# Creating pop-Up alert message in excel without using VBA

Tags: excel

All
Could you advise me about, how could i create a Pop-Up alert message in excel, without using VBA code, for cell containing a formula (Output cell not Input cell)?
Regards,
Thanks.

Comment: You can't. How would you trigger the alert?